# Makefile syntax error. Missing separator

Tags: c++, makefile, external, libraries

I need to understand the syntax of a makefile prior to modify it to fit my own needs. Searching through the net I have been able to understand most of it, but the last part is giving me a syntax error:

Makefile:119: *** missing separator. Stop.

line 119 is the first one here:

```
        rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)
.cpp.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

I don't really get what's being done in these last lines, and I can't seem to find the information I need in the GNU make manual,

Thanks

Comment: @Mat Tried to provide an edit, hopeless! _@D1X_ Note that `TAB` **is relevant** for the makefile syntax. It separates actions from the rules.

Comment: Sorry, I do know TAB is relevant for Makefile syntax, I just new in Stackoverflow. I think it's fixed now. Thank you.

Comment: @D1X _"I do know TAB is relevant for Makefile syntax ..."_ If your makefile text is verbatim as what you're showing, you didn't got the `TAB`s (at least 4 spaces right) to separate the actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've cut-and-pasted from your actual Makefile it's hard to give a certain answer.  If the first line you provided, `rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)` truly is line 119 and the makefile is valid until then, it's likely that you don't have a TAB preceding the `rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)`.  It should look like this:

```
clean:
        rm -rf $(CLEANFILES)
.cpp.o:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.cpp.obj:
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
.c.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `test -f '$<' || echo '$(SRCDIR)/'`$<
.c.obj:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCL) -c -o $@ `if test -f '$<'; then $(CYGPATH_W) '$<'; else $(CYGPATH_W) '$(SRCDIR)/$<'; fi`
```

That is, the command lines in each recipe must have a literal TAB character at the start of the line.